# How to get rid of reminder time issue in slack?

Tags: time, slack

I am currently using slack, it’s a great team work tool. I have one issue though: when I create a remind say, /remind me “abc” at night, it sets the reminding time as 3pm. but this is not night, i would like to have 6pm, or better I can set it myself (i.e., set tonight as 6pm). How can I achieve this? - btw, i live in US west coast

Answer (score 0):

You can use the time itself or a relative time:

```
/remind me "abc" at 6pm CST
/remind me "123" tomorrow night at 8pm CST
/remind me "youandme" 5 hours from now
```

You can also set your timezone data by exploring the `/tz` command

You can set it on the account level by following the instructions [here](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/219889247-Change-your-time-zone).